# GitHub API : Get thread_id from mail notifications (issues, pull requests, ...)

Tags: api, email, github, notifications

I'm currently working on a project using the [GitHub API](https://docs.github.com/en/rest) and ThunderBird.
On this project I need to work with [notifications and threads](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/activity#notifications).

In order to get a `thread_id` needed for some requests (such as `GET /notifications/threads/{thread_id}`), I can use the `GET /notifications` api route which returns an array of notifications with the id of the threads they belong to.

The problem is, I don't want to get the `thread_id` that way but directly from the mail you received when you are mentioned on a thread, for instance : an answer to an issue you asked.

Normally you get a mail that looks like that :
[mail notifications from GitHub](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wGi4S.png).

Unfortunately, I could not find the `thread_id` in the mail (headers, content, ...), the closest thing i could find was the link "unsubscribe" at the end, which leads to the thread.
This url contains what seems to be an id but it's not an `int` and it looks like it's encoded in some base...I tried base64 but the int returned is not working (it's different than the id you get with `/notifications` of the API).

So my question is : is there a way to get the `thread_id` directly from the mail so that I can use it in my project to request the GitHub API ?

Thank you,